# Developing a html 5 game compatible with internet explorer 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

i want to make a HTML 5 game, the only constraint is that the game must run on Internet Explorer 9. Since i use Mac OS, can i develop the game on other Browsers like Safari, FireFox or Chrome? If so, how can i make sure that the game will be running correctly in IE9 when i deliver it? Is there any way for that? Thanx in advance.

Comment: To be 100% sure there won't be any gotchyas, I'd develop under 9 exclusively, since that's what you're targetting.

Answer (score 4):

You should use http://caniuse.com/. Just check all your code with that. Of course, you eventually need to try it on IE9 if you really need it to be reliable in that browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you use established toolkits like jQuery, you should be fine with IE9, but there are some things that will work differently (ie. cached images does not trigger onLoad) on IE.

The only way to make sure is of course running it on the browser itself.
Either through a VM or a service like [Browserling](https://browserling.com/).